# How to eliminate writestringtomemory warning in Web page?

Tags: javascript, browser, deprecated

None of the javascript in my Web page contains the function writeStringToMemory, but I keep seeing warnings in the console that writeStringToMemory is deprecated and to use stringToUTF8() instead.

Where does the deprecated code exist? How do I eliminate this warning?

Answer (score -1):

You’ve probably noticed that when you write something like:

context.getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color_resource_id);

Android Studio will give you a lint message warning you that the Resources#getColor(int) method was deprecated in Marshmallow in favor of the new, Theme-aware Resources#getColor(int, Theme) method. You also probably know by now that the easy alternative to avoiding this lint warning these days is to call:

Comment: Your remarks are interesting but not applicable in this case.